# pymssql: Operational Error in SQL insert statement

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I am inserting into a SQL table using pymssql library in python.

```
server = <SERVER_NAME>
database = <DB_NAME>
password = <password>
LOGIN = <username?
DOMAIN= <DOMAIN_NAME>
username = f'{DOMAIN}\\{LOGIN}'


iot_cnxn1 = pymssql.connect(host=server,database=database,user=username,password=password)
iot_cursor1 = iot_cnxn1.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO [<TABLE_NAME>] VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
sql_data = tuple(map(tuple, tResult.values))
iot_cursor1.executemany(query,sql_data)

iot_cnxn1.commit() 
iot_cnxn1.close()
```

Here **tResult** is a DF which has proper data. I am running this script as part of a job and most of the time it succeeds but few times the below error is logged

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 233, in pymssql._pymssql.Connection.__init__
  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1056, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_non_query
  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1077, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_non_query
  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1232, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 781, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.cancel
  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1840, in pymssql._mssql.assert_connected
pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Not connected to any MS SQL server
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<FILEPATH>/./python.py", line 204, in <module>
    iot_cnxn1 = pymssql.connect(host=server,database=database,user=username,password=password)
  File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 662, in pymssql._pymssql.connect
  File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 235, in pymssql._pymssql.Connection.__init__
pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: Cannot start transaction: Not connected to any MS SQL server
```

Kindly let me know how to handle this or any other way to insert the df into SQL table.

Thanks,

Comment: You could try to connect using a context manager to see if it helps: `with pymssql.connect(host=server,database=database,user=username,password=password) as iot_cnxn1:` `with iot_cnxn1.cursor() as iot_cursor1:` and remove `iot_cnxn1.close()`.